# When I parse YAML with Ruby, it changes my anchor name

Tags: ruby, anchor, yaml

I have a YAML file like this:

```
    - axis: &kadeployversion
   type: user-defined
   name: kadeployversion
   values:
    - kadeploy3
    - kadeploy3-dev
```

I edited this file with Ruby like this:

```
require 'yaml'
jjb = YAML.load_file(fileToParse)
jjb[0]['type']='test'
File.open(fileToParse, 'w+'){
 |f| f.write jjb.to_yaml
}
```

But when I read my new file, I have this:

```
    - axis: &12345678
   type: test
   name: kadeployversion
   values:
    - kadeploy3
    - kadeploy3-dev
```

It works, but I would like to keep my original anchor name, else it'll become unreadable. Any idea?

Comment: I'm working on an answer that I think addresses this, but could you please update your sample input/output to be valid YAML fragments so we can use them as actual test input to guarantee we are answering the right question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using the [mid-level parsing API](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych.rb):

```
stream   = Psych.parse_stream(yaml)
document = stream.children[0]
mapping  = document.children[0]
index    = mapping.children.index {|x|
  x.is_a?(Psych::Nodes::Scalar) && x.value == 'type'
}
mapping.children[index + 1].value = "new type"

puts stream.to_yaml
```

### Explanation

This isn't possible using standard load/dump, since the label information is lost. What is happening when you dump the parsed YAML again is equivalent to:

```
a = [3]
puts({"version"=>a, "axis"=>a}.to_yaml)

###

---
version: &1
- 3
axis: *1
```

An arbitrary ID is applied to label the object.

But you're not out of luck! By dropping down to the psych [mid-level parsing API](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/blob/master/lib/psych.rb), this data is present and you can able to make use of it.

```
yaml = <<EOS
version: &kadeployversion
 - 3
axis: *kadeployversion
type: something
EOS

puts Psych.parse_stream(yaml).to_yaml
###
version: &kadeployversion
- 3
axis: *kadeployversion
type: something
```

`parse_stream` returns an AST rather than plain ruby objects, so the trick now is to update that AST, which is more difficult and potentially brittle than what you had been trying. If you `pp` the return value of `parse_stream` the structure is hopefully easy enough to follow, and you can write some code like the answer at the top.

Comment: Thanks mate! I have to say that the documentation is abysmal, especially in the department of examples for doing anything other than trivial tasks. The idea that "The AST can be freely modified" is a touch less than one needs to actually quickly solve a real problem. Your example fills in the gotcha I ran into that is not clear.